# Add checkbox to a dropdown in plotly dash

Tags: css, checkbox, drop-down-menu, plotly-dash

This might be a FAQ, but I did not find any solution for **plotly dash**. I don't have any html or css knowledge.
**I need to add a checkbox next to every option in the dropdown.**

I also tried to add my custom class to the css stylesheet -

```
.checked[type="checkbox"]:before {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}
```

But, adding this option in className also does not help. *I am not looking for multi=True* , as the user will have to re-open the dropdown again to select next option. The file `/assets/bWLwgP.css` is the usual `bWLwgP.css` downloadable from "https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css"

```
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc

external_stylesheets = ["/assets/bWLwgP.css)"]

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)
app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='demo-dropdown',
        options=[
            {'label': 'New York City', 'value': 'NYC'},
            {'label': 'Montreal', 'value': 'MTL'},
            {'label': 'San Francisco', 'value': 'SF'}
        ],
        value='NYC', multi=False, className="checked"
    ),
    html.Div(id='dd-output-container'), 
])


@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('dd-output-container', 'children'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('demo-dropdown', 'value')])
def update_output(value):
    return 'You have selected "{}"'.format(value)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: So the checkbox's purpose is purely visual? Or is it that you're only allowed to select an option by clicking on the checkbox?

Comment: select multiple options by clicking on the checkboxes

Comment: Has any body found any answer to this question? Not possible for Stackoverflow to find anything that difficult :P

Comment: I would search around on Plotly's own forum for questions like this. Their devs are much better at getting to answer more specific questions such as this one.